# NDSolveValue::fememrc | Defining initial conditions on a part of a 1D mesh

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to solve a simple PDE in the cylindrical coordinates:

$$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \bigg(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial c^2}{\partial r^2}\bigg)$$

The initial and boundary conditions are as follows:

$$ c[t=0,r] = {0,\hspace{2mm} r<=r_0 ;\hspace{2mm} C_b, \hspace{2mm} r> r_0}$$ $$ c[t,r=\infty] = C_b$$ $$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial r}[t,r=0] = 0$$

I wrote the following code in Mathematica:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

ClearAll[DiffCoeff, Cb, c1, r, t, pde, radialDerivative, \
secondRadialDerivative, boundaryConditions, initialCondition, sol, \
AvgConcentration, r0, tmax, inf]

DiffCoeff = 1; Cb = 1; r0 = 1; tmax = 10; inf = 100;

(*Define the PDE with NeumannValue for the flux condition*)
radialDerivative = 1/r*Derivative[1, 0][c1][t, r];
secondRadialDerivative = Derivative[2, 0][c1][t, r];
pde = Derivative[0, 1][c1][t, r] - 
    DiffCoeff*(radialDerivative + secondRadialDerivative) == 
   NeumannValue[0, r == 0];

(*Boundary Condition using DirichletCondition*)
boundaryConditions = 
 DirichletCondition[c1[t, r] == Cb, 
  r == inf];
(*Initial condition:c1(0,r)=0 for r<=r0 and Cb r>r0*)
initialCondition = c1[0, r] == If[r <= r0, 0, Cb];
(*Solve the PDE*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, boundaryConditions, initialCondition}, 
  c1, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, 0, inf}]
```

This solves with a warning:

```
NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

Now, I was trying to solve the warning by smoothening the mesh with the following modification to the code:

```
(*Create a custom mesh*)
mesh = ToGradedMesh[{{Line[{{0}, {2*r0}}], <|
     "MaximalDistance" -> 0.1|>}, {Line[{{2*r0}, {inf}}]}}]
MeshRegion[mesh]

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, boundaryConditions, initialCondition}, 
  c1, {t, 0, tmax}, {r} \[Element] mesh]
```

And this gives an error which I would like to solve:

```
NDSolveValue::femnotime: The differential equation cannot be solved as a time dependent equation as specified, most likely because the initial conditions given at (t==0.`) are not sufficient to define an initial value problem. As a consequence the differential equation will be solved as a time independent equation.

NDSolveValue::fememrc: The ranges {{0.,300.},ElementMesh[{{0.},{0.1},{0.2},{0.3},{0.4},{0.5},{0.6},{0.7},{0.8},{0.9},<<431>>},{LineElement[{{1,2,222},{2,3,223},{3,4,224},{4,5,225},{5,6,226},{6,7,227},{7,8,228},{8,9,229},{9,10,230},{10,11,231},<<210>>},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<210>>}]},{PointElement[{{1},{221}}]},{PointElement[{{1},{221}}]}]} cannot be combined to a region. Please specify a combined region.
```

Now I am open to refining the original mesh in the NDSolve Function itself, maybe using the MaxCellMeasure function. But I want the mesh to be non-uniform. Will MaxCellMeasure allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the derivatives the wrong way round. Try this:

```
(*Define the PDE with NeumannValue for the flux condition*)
radialDerivative = 1/r*Derivative[0, 1][c1][t, r];
secondRadialDerivative = Derivative[0, 2][c1][t, r];
pde = Derivative[1, 0][c1][t, r] - 
    DiffCoeff*(radialDerivative + secondRadialDerivative) == 
   NeumannValue[0, r == 0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will die in shame today :'(

Comment: Can you once explain why my initial and boundary condition are not consistent at r = 100? The boundary condition at r = 100 is the Dirichlet boundary condition, (c1 = Cb). The initial condition at r  = 100 is also (c1 = Cb).

Comment: @Brownian_Motion, you are right I have miss read that and I have removed the statement about that. Note, however, that with the If statement for r=100 you have introduced a jump condition. At, say, at r=99 it's 0 and then it jumps to Cb. Most likely this will numerically not be an issue. For more a physically more correct model a smooth transition for 0 to Cb would be good. And that transition should be representable on the mesh. But again, this is probably minor. Happy FEM-ing.